# Setting up virtual host on XAMPP

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual, host

I've installed XAMPP on Ubuntu in '/opt/lampp' directory and would like to set up some VirtualHosts. Apache Virtual Host tutorial instructs to place

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

code in '/etc/apache2/sites-available/[virtualhostname].conf'. The problem is that I don't have 'apache2' folder in '/etc'. I also don't have 'sites-available' directory in '/opt/lampp/apache2'.

I have '/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf' and '/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf' files though. Which ones shall I use to set the VH up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, but before you should add your servername to your `.hosts` file and uncomment inclusion of of the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in the `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`.