# Apache default configurarion file

Tags: php, apache, configuration-files, lampp, kali-linux

I've installed LAMPP stack that includes Apache, from Apache documentation I understand that if I install Apache form package manager, 
the default configuration file will be `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but if I install it from something else it may be in /opt (which is 
the case here, as I install it with LAMPP stack which locate config file in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`).

now which one is the default config file for Apache? both of them write in the beginning of the file that it's the default page.

DocumentRoot in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` is set to `/opt/lampp/htdocs` and DocumentRoot in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is `www/var/html`, but when I hit `http://localhost/` in URL it takes me to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`. Is that make me sure that the `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` is the default one?

and  why there are two default config file, why there are /etc/apache2 folder at all,

I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963294/setting-up-virtual-host-on-xampp) that said he install XAMPP, and he doesn't has apache2 folder, is that  mean that I install Apache alone after installing LAMPP?(maybe I do it, I really doesn't remember), and is there any bad harm if I delete that apache2 folder?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: on kali linux..

Comment: That is a debian distro. Can't you use apt?

Comment: no,  I use it ...

Comment: so then, do `apt-get install apache2` then there is no need for xamp. And it will put apache2 into /etc/apache2 which is where most things and people expect to find it.

Comment: I prefer Xampp, what I'm asking for is from where this /etc/apache2 come, from your comment it seems that I ran this command before by mistake, and install apache2 alongside with XAMPP .

Comment: Could be. You can remove it using apt.

Answer (score 2):

The DocumentRoot is a good indicator. If it's set to /opt/lampp/htdocs only in one of the files, this is the one being used.